# References in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

Is there a common approach to store serializable references to non-serializable objects in redux state tree?

The simple use case is uploading a [rather big] file to the server from reactjs client. If such upload is a part of form submission algorithm driven by redux actions, we need to keep a reference to the file in the store. The simplest approach would be to keep the entire contents of the file in the store, but this is inefficient for large files.

One of the ways I'm thinking is to introduce a simple map of {`stringkey`:[Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob)} and keep `stringkey` in the state tree. Though in this case we need to implement reference counting or something else to delete unused keys.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I'd steer away from using the store to, er, store large files. It maintains the state for your application, so a reference to the file should be all that is required (incidentally, it is good practice to keep the store normalized, along the lines of database practice).

I'd keep the side affect of uploading the file away from the reducer logic. You can do this with middleware in redux so that the file is uploaded as part of an action; on success a subsequent action updates the store with whatever is needed for subsequent rendering, application state etc. The actual file (if it is needed) can be stored elsewhere and merely referenced from your store.

Comment: I agree and definitely not planning to store files in the store. Trying to avoid using middleware for now, though that could be one of the options. More looking into the proper (and preferably universal) way to reference non-serializable objects from the store. Just though maybe someone already had a universal plug-in solution for that

Comment: OK; best of luck with your project.